# Selector for the child element for the current parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a category list. I wish to toggle my each category items when a click is done on the respective category.

I did the below code. But when I click any of the category, all the category items are toggled. I think the problem is with my selector. What change I should do now.

### HTML

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="main_category">Category1</li>
            <div class="sub_category" style="display: none;">
                <ul>
                    <li>Item1</li>
                    <li>Item2</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        <li class="main_category">Category2</li>
            <div class="sub_category" style="display: none;">
                <ul>
                    <li>Item1</li>
                    <li>Item2</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li.main_category").click(function() {
        $(".sub_category").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to change your HTML markup, (assuming the item will div will remain next to li):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li.main_category").click(function() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle();
    });
});
```

But, I would suggest you to change your markup a little (**because you don't need or may not want divs inside the list**) so that it is cleaner:

```
<div class="nav">
        <ul>
            <li class="main_category">Category1
                    <ul style="display:none">
                        <li>Item1</li>
                        <li>Item2</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            <li class="main_category">Category2
                    <ul style="display:none">
                        <li>Item1</li>
                        <li>Item2</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

And the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li.main_category").click(function() {
        $(this).children("ul").slideToggle();
    });
});
```